# 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm trying to make a video player by using surfaceView and mediaplayer, mediacontroller.
I understand the error is in instance in my code, however, don't know what point to make it fixed.
Related posts in Stackoverflow were seen though I cannot get the point because of my lack of understanding..

Please let me know which point I have to fix.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.project.textureviewvideotest/com.project.textureviewvideotest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/position_anchor"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/play_btn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/position_anchor"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/position_anchor" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/stop_btn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/position_anchor"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/position_anchor" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl  {
    public final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    LinearLayout container;

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Uri video_uri;
    Button playButton;

    MediaController mcontroller;
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context context;

        video_uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + "/raw/testvideo");


        container = findViewById(R.id.container);

        try{
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, video_uri);
            surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

            playButton = findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
            playButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            Button stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_btn);
            stopButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR", e);
        }
    }

    Button.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.play_btn) {
                Log.i("main", "play");
                startOrPause();
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.stop_btn) {
                stopNprepare();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mcontroller.show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"surfaceCreated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        try {


            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);

            mcontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            playButton.setText("Play");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"surfaceDestroyed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    private void startOrPause() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            playButton.setText("Play");
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            playButton.setText("Pause");
        }
    }

    private void stopNprepare() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        playButton.setText("Play");


        try {
            // mediaplayer 재생 준비
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    // Add implement methods to Override
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this){

    };

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int i) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return 0;
    }

    Handler handler;    // android.os.Handler
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mcontroller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        mcontroller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
        mcontroller.setEnabled(true);

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mcontroller.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and provide the *entire* stack trace, not just the first line.

Comment: I guess life cycle issue. You can't use the activity context until your activity created. (i.e., There is an instance variable which will use the activity context, which is not yet defined, "MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this){}") Also, there are lots of warning in the code so you shall probably take care of it.

Comment: But for dedicated issue you ask, it shall due to the mediaController there. Either init it in onCreate() method if you need to use in future or remove it if it is not used at all.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your comment. I'll refer your advise and will post with providing entire stack trace :)

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA Yes! your mentions make it work!! So much thanks for your kind advise!